# AngularJS REST service calls: How to exchange data between provider, controller and directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive

I have two REST web services which I have to call one by one. The first one return some data which I have to use for the second REST service call. The result of the second one, I need to provide it to my directive which should display the values.

I build with AngularJS a **controller** in this way:

```
app.controller('MyRestCtrl', [$scope, 'RestScope', function($scope, RestScope) {
    RestScope.preGet().success(function(data) {
        /* success of the first REST call and do some calculations with this data */
        /* Question: I have to set the calculated data (data1 and data2) to the 
                     RestScope provider, how can I do this, so that the second call 
                     .get() has this data to make the request? */

        RestScope.get().success(function(response) {
            /* response has all the data which I need for my directive */
            /* Question: How can I provide this data into my directive? */
        });
    })
}]);
```

And here is the **provider**:

```
app.provider('RestScope', function() {
    this.data1 = null;
    this.data2 = null;
    this.setData1 = function(_data1) {
        this.data1 = _data1;
    }
    this.setData2 = function(_data2) {
        this.data2 = _data2;
    }

    this.$get = ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
        var _data1 = this.data1;
        var _data2 = this.data2;
        function get() {
            return $http.get('http://www.test.com/' + _data1 + '/?param=' + _data2);
        }
        function preGet() {
            return $http.get('http://www.test.com/getData/');
        }
        return {
            get: get,
            preGet: preGet
        };
    }];
});
```

And here is my **directive**:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC', 
        replace: false, 
        templateUrl: 'path/to/my.html'
    };
});
```

So the first thing is how to set inside of the `preGet().success` some data to the `RestScope` provider? And the second question if I get the data of the second call `get().success` how to provide it to my directive?

Comment: you already have `getter` and `setter` methods, why can't you just use them in success of first call?

Comment: How can I do this? It seems I am not inside the right scope?! ``this.setData1(data)`` returns me an error: ``TypeError: Unable to get property 'setData1' or undefined or null reference``.

Comment: Does `get()` always require `preGet()`? i.e. would you ever call one without then calling the other?

Comment: Yes, ``preGet()`` returns data I need to create the REST call inside ``get()``, so, yes, I need ``preGet`` always running before ``get``.

Comment: you need to use `RestScope.setData1`, that's why you injected `RestScope`